# Android reset app functionality

Tags: android, reset

Is there any way I can implement functionality which will clear all my data/files/shared_preferences/database in my application. I need functionality like Clear Data button in Android App Settings.

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Comment: Be clear , u want to clear file from SD Card or Shared Preference .

Comment: I want to get the clear data functionality. Not clearing files from SD Card. I want to reset my application.Clear all files/shared preferences/databases all from internal storage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This link might be helpful for you 

http://www.hrupin.com/2011/11/how-to-clear-user-data-in-your-android-application-programmatically

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
private static MyApplication instance;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    instance = this;
}

public static MyApplication getInstance() {
    return instance;
}

public void clearApplicationData() {
    File cache = getCacheDir();
    File appDir = new File(cache.getParent());
    if (appDir.exists()) {
        String[] children = appDir.list();
        for (String s : children) {
            if (!s.equals("lib")) {
                deleteDir(new File(appDir, s));
                Log.i("TAG", "**************** File /data/data/APP_PACKAGE/" + s + " DELETED *******************");
            }
        }
    }
}

public static boolean deleteDir(File dir) {
    if (dir != null &amp;&amp; dir.isDirectory()) {
        String[] children = dir.list();
        for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
            boolean success = deleteDir(new File(dir, children[i]));
            if (!success) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    return dir.delete();
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Trying to do "DROP DATABASE database_name" ?